# Django datatables load ajax data load

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, datatable

Probably I haven't yet understand how the urls.py works...but I don't know how to load the data with "bServerSide" of datatables... I think to have a problem with my urls.py. I use Django, datatables.js and this is my code:

## main.html

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="example1">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#example1').dataTable( {                 
             "bServerSide": true,
             "sAjaxSource": "main.html/getdata_json",
             "bProcessing": true,
         } );
     } );
 </script>
```

## views.py

```
def myajaxview(request):
   report = []
   start = request.GET['iDisplayStart']
   length = request.GET['iDisplayLength']    
   query = name.objects.all() #or any kind of queryset       
   query = query[start:start+length]
   for q in query:
      report.append(json.dumps(q.nome_struttura))    
   json = json.dumps(report)
   return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
```

## urls.py

```
  urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
      ...
      url(r'^getdata_json$', 'views.myajaxview'),
      ...
```

I don't know where is the error. Can you help me please?

Comment: Why have you got "main.html" in your sAjaxSource value?

Comment: Because if I don't put "main.html" in sAjaxSource I get "Page not found (404)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to avoid writing urls in more than one place (follow the DRY principle), you can give a [name to your url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns), like this:

```
url(r'^getdata_json$', 'views.myajaxview', name='getdata_json')
```

Then in HTML use Django builtin template tag [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url) to retrieve the view url:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="example1"
    data-url="{% url 'getdata_json' %}">
```

Then in JS you can use jQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to retrieve the URL (instead of hardcoding it):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#example1').dataTable( {                 
         "bServerSide": true,
         "sAjaxSource": $(this).data('url'),
         "bProcessing": true,
     } );
 } );
 </script>
```

As a side note, you could just append *q.nome_struttura* to your *report* array, using json.dumps on the final array, like this:

```
for q in query:
    report.append(q.nome_struttura)
json = json.dumps(report)
```

In general, when you are using AJAX requests you should use a browser developer tool (like Firebug for Firefox or Chrome Developer tools) to see exactly what data are passed to the server and how the response goes.

For your information there is a [third party Django app](https://pypi.org/project/django-datatables-view/) meant exactly for your use case: that is integrating Django with jQuery Datatables with server side processing.

Comment: thanks for your respond but I get ever page not found.. $(this).data('url') in undefined.

Comment: I replace $(this).data('url')  width {% url 'getdata_json' %} and I get the data! How can I show the data in the table now?